# Error executing statement: Invalid null or zero-element list of select clause expression types

Tags: esper

Can we write update statements in on demand query based on certain criteria?
I am trying to execute following query :
update istream StockEventWindow set price = 100 where price > 250 and id = 10;

But i am getting following error 
Error executing statement: Invalid null or zero-element list of select clause expression types [update istream StockEventWindow set price = 100 where price > 250 and id = 10 ]

My task is to update events having price greater than 250 after certain time interval from the time event is received.

It would be great if someone gives solution with an example of using update query on demand. Also if possible, give an example of delete command usage in on demand query.

I tried on demand update and delete commands as mentioned in esper documentation 6.10.2 and 6.10.3 ([Link](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.3.0/esper-reference/html/nwtable.html#named_update_faf%60)). But it is giving error.

when using delete i am getting following error :
`com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementSyntaxException: Incorrect syntax near 'delete' (a reserved keyword) [delete from StockEventWindow where id = 10]
    at com.espertech.esper.epl.parse.ExceptionConvertor.convertStatement(ExceptionConvertor.java:40)
    at com.espertech.esper.epl.parse.ParseHelper.parse(ParseHelper.java:121)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorHelper.compileEPL(EPAdministratorHelper.java:115)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorHelper.compileEPL(EPAdministratorHelper.java:88)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.getExecuteMethod(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1456)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.executeQueryInternal(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1414)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.executeQuery(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1407)
    at com.cor.cep.handler.Listener.onDemandUpdate(Listener.java:155)
    at com.cor.cep.handler.Listener.update(Listener.java:76)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementResultServiceImpl.dispatchInternal(StatementResultServiceImpl.java:389)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementResultServiceImpl.processDispatch(StatementResultServiceImpl.java:249)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementResultServiceImpl.execute(StatementResultServiceImpl.java:235)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.UpdateDispatchViewBase.execute(UpdateDispatchViewBase.java:75)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.UpdateDispatchFutureSpin.execute(UpdateDispatchFutureSpin.java:85)
    at com.espertech.esper.dispatch.DispatchServiceImpl.dispatchFromQueue(DispatchServiceImpl.java:52)
    at com.espertech.esper.dispatch.DispatchServiceImpl.dispatch(DispatchServiceImpl.java:31)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.dispatch(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1238)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processTimeEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:529)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:423)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.sendEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:197)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.timerCallback(EPRuntimeImpl.java:171)
    at com.espertech.esper.timer.EPLTimerTask.run(EPLTimerTask.java:61)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

and when using update it is giving error :
`com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementSyntaxException: Incorrect syntax near 'StockEventWindow' expecting 'istream' but found an identifier at line 1 column 7 [update StockEventWindow set price = 200 where id = 10]
    at com.espertech.esper.epl.parse.ExceptionConvertor.convertStatement(ExceptionConvertor.java:40)
    at com.espertech.esper.epl.parse.ParseHelper.parse(ParseHelper.java:109)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorHelper.compileEPL(EPAdministratorHelper.java:115)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorHelper.compileEPL(EPAdministratorHelper.java:88)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.getExecuteMethod(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1456)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.executeQueryInternal(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1414)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.executeQuery(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1407)
    at com.cor.cep.handler.Listener.onDemandUpdate(Listener.java:155)
    at com.cor.cep.handler.Listener.update(Listener.java:76)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementResultServiceImpl.dispatchInternal(StatementResultServiceImpl.java:389)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementResultServiceImpl.processDispatch(StatementResultServiceImpl.java:249)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementResultServiceImpl.execute(StatementResultServiceImpl.java:235)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.UpdateDispatchViewBase.execute(UpdateDispatchViewBase.java:75)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.UpdateDispatchFutureSpin.execute(UpdateDispatchFutureSpin.java:85)
    at com.espertech.esper.dispatch.DispatchServiceImpl.dispatchFromQueue(DispatchServiceImpl.java:52)
    at com.espertech.esper.dispatch.DispatchServiceImpl.dispatch(DispatchServiceImpl.java:31)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.dispatch(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1238)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processThreadWorkQueueLatchedSpin(EPRuntimeImpl.java:870)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processThreadWorkQueue(EPRuntimeImpl.java:778)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processWrappedEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:477)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:438)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.sendEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:197)
    at com.cor.cep.handler.StockEventHandler.handle(StockEventHandler.java:336)
    at com.cor.cep.util.RandomStockEventGenerator$1.run(RandomStockEventGenerator.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: is "StockEventWindow" a named window? The update-istream is for events in flight. For updating named window events I use "on update".

Comment: Yes StockEventWindow is a named window.In esper documentation  it is written that we can use update for named window but when i am using the syntax mentioned there, its giving me error saying  `Incorrect syntax near 'StockEventWindow' expecting 'istream' but found an identifier at line 1 column 8 [ update StockEventWindow set price = 200 where id = 10]` .

Answer (score 1):

There are two APIS, one for creating continuous queries (createEPL) and one for executing fire-and-forget queries (executeQuery). It is best to not mix them up. The "on update" is a continuous queries and the "update window ..." is a fire-and-forget query.